# Distribute words according to frequency CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm looking to see if someone has already done something similar (I'm sure I've seen it out there).

Basically I'd like to display an array of words in a way that words that have most number of occurrences are greater in size that others with less number of occurrences.

I'd like to use CSS/HTML, so I can change the colors and background of where the words are.

Any suggestion or alternative is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: You would most definitely need JavaScript or PHP. Also, what have *you* tried so far? Any specific problems on the way?

Comment: Thanks for response Daniel. I'm just not sure how to tackle it, and before developing something from scratch, I wanted to see first if someone has done something similar (I'm not very handy with CSS).

Comment: `$a=array("A","Cat","Dog","A","Dog");
$ordered_array = array_count_values($a);` will do what you want in PHP. Just change the values in the array to what you need. `$ordered_array` will be an array with the index having the value of the word, and the value the number of times it occures in the array.

Comment: No no... I'm having trouble explaining what I want to do:
Imagine I have an multidimensional array of words, there's number associated with each word (which means the number of occurrences of that word in the database). Then I want to display these words in a fancy way, but want their size to depend on the number in the array (the greater the number, the bigger the size of the letters in the word).

Hope it makes sense?

Comment: ok, I think I understand the problem better now. Could you add relevant code to the question? It will be easier helping you that way.

Comment: What you are describing is called "word cloud" or "tag cloud" (stop torturing him^^)

Comment: oh god @Winchestro you're the man!!! Geez, I couldn't figure out what it called!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for actually has a name, it's called Word or Tag Cloud.

Thanks Winchestro!